# I have a MSc degree, want to apply for PhD degree. Should I submit my BSc transcript during admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters

I have a BSc and an MSc degree on Computer Science. My BSc CGPA was too low. I somehow got accepted to an MSc degree(two years) and got 4.00 CGPA. I think I am good at my field.

Now I want to apply for a PhD degree, but all universities I checked requires transcripts received from all higher education attended so far.

I don't want to submit my BSc transcript. Is there a way for me to get accepted to a PhD programme without submitting BSc degree? Is there any chance that my MSc transcript override my previous(BSc) degree?

Comment: Regardless of what your undergrad GPA was, not submitting a transcript would be a more negative reflection on your application

Comment: I've personally witnessed a few occasions where students were rejected from PhD programs due to poor undergrad GPA even though they had amazing master's GPA (which is prompted [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/157940/why-do-phd-admission-committees-focus-on-your-bachelors-degree-grades-when-you)).  You may want to avoid submitting if not strictly required.

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead and submit your undergraduate transcript.  The admissions committee will be expecting to see one and your application might be screened out before consideration simply because this transcript is missing.

The fact that you've had good grades in your master's program may help you to overcome the bad impression left by your poor undergraduate GPA.  Having good letters of recommendation and one or more publications (of high quality) will help a lot more.

Comment: So, can a very successful MSc degree erase all the bad impressions of a BSc degree?

Comment: I'm afraid that your bad BSc grades will still leave a bit of a bad impression- you certainly need to address this in your application, mostly by highlighting your recent success and explaining what has changed in your life so that you now are a good student.

Answer (score 0):

Application components should be clearly stated for the institution you are applying. If they ask for a  transcript and you do not provide one, you likely will not be accepted.